# Annotate parameter as function accepting several types as params for closure compiler

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I want to annotate a parameter to a method call to be a function accepting two parameters, first being Error or null and second being an Object or Array of objects. However I seem to not be able to figure out the correct annotation - compiler always gives  Bad type annotation.

Example:

```
  /**
   * Allows to predefine the callback for a named 'run' method. This is
   * useful mostly for application code that has only one consumer for any
   * particular named request.
   *
   * @param {!string} run_name The name of the run to register default callback
   * for.
   * @param {function(Error, (Array.<Object>|Object)): undefined} callback The callback
   * function to execute for the named request if no other callback is provided
   * with the request.
   */
  _.registerRunCallback = function(run_name, callback) {
    this.internalImplementation(run_name, callback);
  };
```

I am not sure if this is actually possible, but I find it to be better than using unknown type.

So my question is how do I do that.

Comment: Are you using the latest release? Simple tests with your example code compile just fine for me. Or perhaps the error happens with your annotations for `this.internalImplementation`.

Comment: Yup latest compiler fix it. Thanks